# Facet Grid with Time Series

Tags: time-series, line, scale, facet-wrap, facet-grid

I am trying to create a time series graph by year using facet_grid so that the data is plotted above each other. However, when I plot it, there is a lot of blank space due to how the data is broken out (ie the 2017 graph still shows the time series for 2018 and 2019 but with no data, I would like to remove this blank space). How can I free the scale of the x coordinates so it does not show all years?

My Code

```
proportion_data %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = new_date, group = 1)) + 
geom_line(aes(y = prop_elect, color ="elect_prop")) +
geom_line(aes(y = prop_water, color ="water_prop")) +
geom_line(aes(y = prop_natgas, color ="natgas_prop")) +
facet_grid(Year ~., scales = "free" )
```

[`Utilities by Year`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5wGN.png)

My Data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuLnV.png)

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks, 
Kris

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the space option?
`facet_grid(Year ~., scales = "free" ,space="free_x")`
Another option is to use `facet_wrap` instead of `facet_grid`
`facet_wrap(~Year, scales = "free" )`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Adding space didnt change the x-axis, looks like that argument changes the space between the graphs. Facet_wrap is the look I want but I'd love to have the graphs on top of each other rather than side by side.

Comment: How about using ncol option in face_wtapnto arrange them as one column?

Comment: It looks decent side by side but it isnt great for comparisons.  I ended up turning the months into numbers (ie January = 1, February = 2).  Thanks for your suggestions Jayamary!